# PrimeNG Datatable check checkboxes in code

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

How can I loop through a datatable and check some of the boxes? 
I need to show the client to which departments a user belongs in a datatable so the client can check or uncheck the rows...

Thanks in advance!

### Edit

Someone on Reddit replied that I can use two-way binding to do this:
`<p-dataTable [value]="cars" selectionMode="multiple" [(selection)]="selectedCars">`

And create an array of selectedCars like this in your component: 
`selectedCars = [cars[0], cars[5]];`

Comment: Show some code what you have tried ? else at least provide which data table of primeng you have used in your code

Comment: @Pardeep There is only one DataTable in PrimeNG. The other ways of displaying data are named different, like DataList and DataGrid. [link](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable) But I have found I can create an array and use this to select them in the DataTable: `<p-dataTable [value]="cars" selectionMode="multiple" [(selection)]="selectedCars">` I forgot about the two-way binding.... But thanks for the reply!!!!!